# Print out separate counter for each list at once

Tags: python, list, csv, counter

I have 6 months of call detail records, containing information e.g. how many sms were sent and if they were outgoing (sortant) or incoming (entrant).

I want a code that tells me something like

```
March: 24566 #amount of outgoing sms  
April : 24667  #amount of outgoing sms  
etc etc.
```

The problem is that when I use counter, python ends up adding up each month to another and shows me the sum of all as a result for the last month.

How should I modify counter so that it does only print out the counter for each list at once ?

How far I have come:

```
import csv
counter = 0

Mois = ['C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/octobre12.csv','C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/novembre12.csv','C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/mars13.csv','C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/avril13.csv','C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/mai13.csv','C:/Users/kwrk9327/Desktop/juin13.csv']
for element in Mois:
    print (element)

    with open(element, 'r',encoding="utf8",errors='ignore') as csvfile:
        reader=csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter=';')

        for line in reader:
            if line[4]=='SMS'and line [1]=='Sortant':
                    counter= counter+1
    print("The result for", element, counter)
```

Comment: What do you mean by at once? Doesn't this code do that after `counter=0` for each element?

Answer (score 1):

you need to reset counter for each csv file. At the moment you reset it only once in the beginning, so only the count for the first file/month is correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to zero out counter after `with` statement before `for` statement:

```
with open(element, 'r',encoding="utf8",errors='ignore') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader (csvfile, delimiter=';')
    counter = 0
    for line in reader
```